# Automatically saving shell history in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Is there an easy way to automatically save every command I execute in shell-mode buffer? I'm running things like python and lua from Emacs' shell buffer and want to save those in addition to regular bash commands.

Default behavior saves history in in .history or .bash_history, but it does not save input to subprocesses. As an example, if I do the following

```
ls /export/hda3/tmp
python
a=2+3
import sys
sys.exit()
ls /export/hda3/tmp
```

the following gets saved

```
#1328903075
ls /export/hda3/tmp
#1328903081
python
#1328903087
ls /export/hda3/tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

Commands are saved automatically, only you need to make sure to actually exit the shell. If you simply kill the shell buffer then no commands will be saved.

I added a check to emacs exit to warn me if I have an open shell buffer, so that I can exit it manually:

```
(defun my-check-if-no-shell-buffer-exists ()
  (if (not (get-buffer "*shell*"))
      t
    (message "you have a shell buffer, make sure you exit it manually")
    nil))

(add-hook 'kill-emacs-query-functions 'my-check-if-no-shell-buffer-exists)
```

It would even be better if the shell buffer would do it automatically when killing the buffer. I think it's a bug in emacs that it fails to do that.

**Edit**: I noticed I have a setting which prevented running process warnings when emacs exits and that's why I needed the above function. If you get a warning about a running shell already when exiting, then you don't need it, you only need to exit the shell manually to save history.

Comment: You mean they are saved by Emacs automatically? (if so, where?) Bash itself doesn't save the commands in my case because I'm running another process on top (ie, Python interpreter)

Comment: I checked and it is written to ~/.history and everything is there (bash, python commands, etc.). Everyting you type into the shell is there.

Comment: Correction: in the previous comment I said bash, though I'm on windows and don't use bash, so I should have said command prompt instead. It may or may not be the same if the underlying shell is bash, though emacs itself does the saving of typed shell commands, so it shouldnt' be much different.

Comment: strange, I have no "~/.history" file

Comment: OK, it's saved in ~/.bash_history, but things I run inside shell subprocesses are not saved.

Comment: In shell.el here is this code: http://pastebin.com/9nj1ca8C  Apparently, if it detects a bash shell then it lets bash do its thing and only uses ~/.history (and therefore writes its own history) if it does not know which shell it is.

Comment: Ah I see, here's a relevant part I found `(defcustom shell-dumb-shell-regexp (purecopy "cmd\\(proxy\\)?\\.exe")
  "Regexp to match shells that don't save their command history, and
don't handle the backslash as a quote character.  For shells that
match this regexp, Emacs will write out the command history when the
shell finishes, and won't remove backslashes when it unquotes shell
arguments."`

Comment: Why wouldn't we just add `(input-send "exit")` followed by `comint-send-input`?